# Random Memory Reads vs Random Memory Writes

Tags: c

In low level languages like C I know you should try to use the CPU cache to your benefit as much as possible. As a cache miss means your program will temporarily have to wait for the RAM to dereference a pointer. However are writes to memory also effected by this? If you write to memory it would seem that the CPU does not need to wait on a response.

I'm trying to decide if reordering a array of items would truly be worth it when I need to access items in the array in certain groups repeatedly (so sorting it based on those groups). However those groups will frequently change so I would need to keep reordering the array if I do this.

Comment: That depends. Do you have write-buffers? What is your caching policy for cache-missing writes? What is your desired memory consistency?

Comment: 1) C is a high-level language. It just provide low abstraction. 2) In **any** language you should concentrate on writing readable and maintainable code. Don't do premature optimisations. 3) In addition to @EOF : which architecture? What is you **specific** problem? What is the access pattern? 4) In what terms are pointers related to caching? What alternative to using pointers are you after?

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer has nothing to do with a cache miss.  A cache miss means memory needs to either be fetched or paged in.  It's all about data locality.  That being said, I agree with Olaf--do not prematurely optimize.  Identify the problem and then identify the cause of the problem and then identify an appropriate solution.  If you think in terms of data locality during your design stage and have a clean implementation then you usually (but not always) will have sufficient performance without focusing on the cache level.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I mean, C is a high level language compared to assembly code but low level compared to something like Java (I'm still kind of new to C)

Comment: I guess I should be more descriptive of what I'm trying todo I'm trying to decide if reordering a array of items would truly be worth it when I need to access items in the array in certain groups (so sorting it based on those groups). However those groups will also frequently change so I would need to keep reordering the array if I did that

Comment: Without knowing more, the bottom line will depend on the array size. If what you are trying to accomplish is locating one item within a group and then performing a sequential read of the remaining group elements rather than having to locate/find each of the remaining elements in the group one-by-one, then the only way to make that call is to actually time your group access times sorted/unsorted with real data sets. If it turn out to be true, resorting with `qsort` is efficient and it if takes substantially less time to sort and access the group - that's the way to go, if not, then not.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your architecture, random memory writes can be expensive for at least two reasons.

1. On today's multi-core machines, almost all writes will require some kind of cache coherence protocol to be run so that the corresponding cache lines on other caches will be invalidated.
2. In terms of ordinary writes, they will either always cost a memory operation or sometimes cause a memory operation depending on whether the cache is write-through or write-back.

You can read more details about the possible behaviors of caches on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache).

Comment: This applies to writes in general and does not answer the **random** writes.

Comment: @Arash, Random writes are also writes. This answered the question as originally formulated, but the OP has updated their question.

Answer (score -2):

This is a very broad question, so my answer is nearly as broad.

The source code, the compiled code, and the underlying hardware are not necessarily all in sync when it comes to reading and writing memory.  Your C/C++ code simply references variables.  The compiled code will turn that into appropriate machine language which is close to the source code but can vary in the case of optimization, volatile keyword, etc.  Finally the hardware will optimize the 3 main levels of storage:  CPU cache (fastest), RAM, and hard disk (yes, your program variables can actually be stored on the hard disk, in the case of swapping).

Whether the CPU waits or not depends partially on what's going on at the hardware layer combined with the machine code (again for example consider data specified as volatile).

Comment: wondering why this is being voted down.  OP seems to be asking if mem writes wait or not.